# Hierarchical select ajax conflict in custom bootstrap theme

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, taxonomy-terms

I have created a custom theme from scratch using twitter Bootstrap. In my content type there is Taxonomy term Hierarchical Select (HS) list.

**Problem:** When authenticated user try to select any term from first level, HS keeps on loading...for ever.

**Note:** Hierarchical select is working fine for admin with core Seven theme enabled and with jQuery update version 7.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Colorbox which was conflicting with HS. I disabled the colorbox module and it worked perfectly. I don't know why this happens, but this should be raised as an issue since both are contrib modules.

Comment: I got the same problem and resolved by the suggested solution!! Thanks~ save my day

Comment: I don't have colorbox module enabled, but still have issue with Bootstrap sub-theme.